# Viewpager swip delay

Tags: android, service, android-viewpager

I'm using viewpager to show music and on swip left/right changing music according to that.When i swip viewpager it takes few sec in swip(it doesnot swip smoothly).

**Code:**

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCurrentPage > arg0) {
            try {
                Constant.position--;
                musicService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MusicService.class);
                musicService.putExtra(Constant.NEXT, Constant.PREVIOUS);
                startService(musicService);
                musicService = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Constant.position++;
                musicService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MusicService.class);
                musicService.putExtra(Constant.NEXT, Constant.NEXT);
                startService(musicService);
                musicService = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mCurrentPage = arg0;
    }
```

whenever I remove this code from onPageSelected, it swip smoothly. I had also putted this code inside handler but no befinits same issue.
Suggest me where I'm doing wrong and how to resolver this.

**Update:**

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sPosition = Constant.position;
                if (intent != null) {
                    try {
                        mPrevious = (String) intent.getExtras().get(
                                Constant.NEXT);
                        System.out.println("value of previous=" + mPrevious);
                        if (mPrevious.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.PLAY)) {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                                cancelNotification();
                            } else {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                buildNotification(title, album);
                            }
                        } else if (mPrevious
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.PREVIOUS)) {
                            playPrevious();
                        } else if (mPrevious.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.NEXT)) {
                            playNext();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        });
        mThread.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the guide topic Services:

> Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, you should start a new thread inside the service

Make sure your music service starts a thread to delegate work to.

Comment: yeah right,I have already used Handler inside service mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
 @Override
    public void run() {
});
But same issue not working smoothly And when i remove code from onPageSelected then its working smoothly

Comment: The service is running in your apps process and on your apps main thread by default.  Can you post the handler logic from your service?

Comment: Hmmm, a workaround might be to add a post delayed handler to that swipe call in your activity.  This way you can smoothly swipe, and then start the music service after some short delay.

Comment: You might also try specifying that the service should run in a different process in your manifest.